# How to get current time stamp in android?

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, timestamp

I want to get current Timestamp in this **YYYY-MM-DDTHHmmssZ** .For instance; Expected value : 2016-01-01%2000:00:00. I have tried various methods,One of them is below :

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").format(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Still I am facing the error (didn't getting expected output which is 2016-01-01%2000:00:00) , Any help will be appreciate,thanks.

Comment: "Still I am facing the error" -- please edit your question and explain, **in detail**, what "the error" is. Also, AFAIK, `SimpleDateFormat` does not have a `format()` method that takes a `Timestamp`.

Comment: Edited @CommonsWare

Comment: Well, it is not 1 January 2016. Where I am, it is 6 October 2016. Hence, you will not get `2016-01-01 00:00:00`, unless you changed your device/emulator to set the date to 1 January 2016. And the `00:00:00` part will vary depending on the time that you execute the code.

Comment: Of course , That is just for reference

Answer (score 7):

just use this:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss");
String format = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
Log.d("MainActivity", "Current Timestamp: " + format);
```

just change the format in which you want current time stamp.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

Your question is ambiguous but according to my understanding:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
```

You haven to **set the timezone**, like:

```
private static SimpleDateFormat df
    = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssz")
 df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

OR

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));           
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date())); //-prints-> 2015-01-22T03:23:26Z
```

If you want to learn more. please refer to:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/dormant/feedparser/trunk/src/java/org/apache/commons/feedparser/tools/ISO8601DateParser.java